# Do we need the "foreign" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

So far, there are just two questions tagged [foreign](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign). Do we really need it?

Comment: Note that one of the questions that uses it is closed. (I have no opinion one way or the other about what this means for the fate of the tag.)

Comment: The tags ... have been taken care of.

Comment: I am closing this question as it is now not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

I am under the impression that unused tags are automatically pruned from the system. If they get used, great. If not, they are cleaned out. We won't need to deal with that manually.

Comment: Unused tags are those tags that are not used by any questions; in this case, the tag is used by two questions, and the system doesn't remove tags in this case. That is why, if we eventually decide the tag is not necessary, the tag needs to be manually removed from all the questions that use it.

Comment: @kia: Okay, here is the appropriate link. As far as I can tell, it only [prunes tags used exactly once](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418). If this is true than it would _not_ pick up the foreign tag.