# The links posted under a question are split on two lines

Tags: support, design, questions

See [Do we need the "foreign" tag?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868/do-we-need-the-foreign-tag)

The links that I see under that question are split on two lines. It happened after I voted to close my question as it is not relevant, now that there are not questions using that tag.

[image: screenshot #1]

To make a comparison, this is what I see for another question, which was not asked by me.

[image: screenshot #2]

Comment: Strange. And no-repro here (as in, I can't see it on *your* question; obviously, I can't try to reproduce it by voting to close myself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a bug — you have the rollback ability on your question or post as the owner.

We also added "protect" as an ability for 15k rep users.

Therefore when protect and rollback appear, the menu wraps.

Comment: Reproduced by activating the [SE Modifications](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-an) user script that adds a few entries to the link menu. Jeff's right that the menu must wrap when it's getting too long. It's a bit unfortunate, though, that it wraps in that spot, between "close" and the number of close votes. Arguably, those two belong together and should be connected with an `&nbsp;` or put in a `nowrap` span or something.